# Is there something annoying about using iframe on ipad?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

What would prevent me from using an iframe to embed another page on another trusted site ?

Comment: Your question and your question title ask two different questions.  Please edit your question and make it clearer.

Comment: I think using iFrames was discouraged in the iPad, but you can used them as long as you thing they work ;)

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on what you want to do. If the iframe will contain scrollable content I advice against it unless you make it really obvious to the user that in that specific region of the screen he will have to use TWO fingers to scroll.

Comment: As someone who does a lot of web surfing on the iPad, iframes are definitely annoying due to the two-finger drag requirement. It's a UI implementation that makes perfect sense, as the browser needs to know whether you want to scroll the whole page or just the iframe, but it's still not fun, especially if you have to do it a lot. As @pellepim noted, it needs to be very clear that I need to use my two-finger scroll to see something or I'll miss the extra content entirely.

Comment: I just want to add also, that the same user experience goes for other document elements, such as DIVs. If they contain scrollable content, iPad and iPhone users will have to use two fingers.